# Eclipse quicktip wont show "import" suggestions in Linux Ubuntu and Centos

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, ubuntu, adt

Although I've seen this question asked on multiple sites, I have not found a working solution.

Issue:  When the eclipse tooltips pops up, all suggested “import” fields remain blank.

What I've tried:
I have changed the Ubuntu font as suggested https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=412021
I have change foreground/background colors as suggested https://askubuntu.com/questions/45001/how-to-fix-black-tooltips-in-eclipse
and 
https://plus.google.com/100162564505001485828/posts/WHBrbEyWPZk

I have tested this on Centos with the same issue.
I have tried different versions of ADT and eclipse

I am running Ubuntu 13.04 ADT with Eclipse version 4.2.1
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This bug identifies the problem
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=412021

To fix, open your preferences, then go to General->Appearence->Colors and Fonts. Then change the font for Basic -> Dialog Font to anything but "Ubuntu". I choose Droid Sans and the problem went away.

Comment: Are you sure that is what the issue was? I went through the steps discribes (Ubuntu was not an option), reset my instance of elipse, and the issue persists.

Comment: When you are at General->Appearence->Colors and Fonts, change the font for Basic > Dialog Font. This works for Eclipse 4.3 on Ubuntu 13.10