# Eclipse shows incomplete links in tooltips

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, ubuntu

I've been living with a very annoying problem in Eclipse where if I declare a type that cannot be uniquely resolved, the tooltip that prompts me to choose the correct class sometimes does not display the full link.

As seen in the screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtqKU.png), I have 9 different Version classes in my workspace, and only 3 of them display properly in the tooltip. The other 6 links still work, but I'd have to click on them first to see exactly which one gets imported.

I've had this problem for quite a while now, and updating to the latest Kepler release did not help. Has anyone else seen this problem or any idea how to debug this?

Specs:

Ubuntu x64 13.10

Eclipse 3.7.2 ~ 4.3.1

Comment: You can refer to the below link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18989605/eclipse-quicktip-wont-show-import-suggestions-in-linux-ubuntu-and-centos

Comment: Thank you! The solution in that thread did not apply to my system but it pointed me in the right direction. Spent the past 10 minutes playing with various dialogue fonts in my Eclipse and found only a handful that displays correctly. Still not sure if the underlying issue is with my system configurations, but at least I found a font that does work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Anuparna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3228726/anuparna?tab=profile) provided the link in the comment which resolves my issue.

*Edit
Solution:
Go to *General->Appearence->Colors and Fonts: Basic > Dialog Font* and play around with the settings until you find something that works.